# Insufficient permission to read system memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I am using a code to scan a the program memory, I use a code to scan the notepad.exe and the program can scan without any problem, but when I want to scan some system process (ex: dwm.exe, Registry) I don't have enough permission, the program can't scan, what can I do? I already tried to run as an administrator.

```cpp
char* scanMemory(DWORD dwmPID)
{

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwmPID);
    if (process)
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
        std::vector<char> chunk;
        char* p = 0;

        while (p < si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress)
        {
            if (VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info))
            {
                p = (char*)info.BaseAddress;
                chunk.resize(info.RegionSize);
                SIZE_T bytesRead;
                if (ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &chunk[0], info.RegionSize, &bytesRead))
                {
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < (bytesRead - 4); ++i)
                    {

                        if (memcmp(".exe", &chunk[i], 4) == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "Found";
                            system("PAUSE");
                        }

                    }
                }
                p += info.RegionSize;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per docs on the winapi "The entire area to be read must be accessible, and if it is not accessible, the function fails." Maybe here is your reason. Not all the memory is accesible to read by external processes. Imagine the problems that may cause. :)

Comment: But a program called process hacker 2 can read the memory of the process dwm.exe, I just don't know how I can have the same permissions that process hacker 2 has

Comment: When you run hacker 2, does the system stop and ask for administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes...But, my program run with admin too

Comment: In addition to running your program with admin privileges, you'll need to explicitly adjust your process' token with the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege before you open a handle to the remote process.  This enables full memory access to the remote process in all but a small handful of critical system processes.  There are many code snippets illustrating how to do this floating around.  Query your favorite search engine for "SE_DEBUG_NAME elevate privileges"

Comment: `VirtualQueryEx` is the precursor to a TOCTTOU race. You cannot reliably read from a process unless that process is at a point where its state cannot change.

Comment: @byteptr i tried give SE_DEBUG_NAME privileges, but the same problem is happening

Comment: Which API is failing and what is GetLastError() reporting?

Comment: See this [link](https://sensepost.com/blog/2020/masquerading-windows-processes-like-a-doubleagent./); it contains one of the shortest snippets of code to gain SE_DEBUG_NAME I've seen sofar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important system processes are protected, first thing you should do is elevate permissions with SeDebugPrivelage:

```
bool SetDebugPrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken{ nullptr };
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
        return false;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TokenPrivileges{};
    TokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValueA(nullptr, "SeDebugPrivilege", &TokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
    }

    if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &TokenPrivileges, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), nullptr, nullptr) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return true;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to hijack/duplicate handles/tokens from processes that have higher permissions.  You can learn how to enumerate process handles from usermode and hijack them by checking out [this source code](https://github.com/Broihon/GH-Injector-Library/blob/master/GH%20Injector%20Library/Handle%20Hijacking.cpp)

It's also possible you do not have full access to all processes due to Protected Processes.

Protected Processes Resources:

- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-1-pass-hash-mitigations-windows-81/
- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-2-exploitjailbreak-mitigations-unkillable-processes-and/
- https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/protected-processes-part-3-windows-pki-internals-signing-levels-scenarios-signers-root-keys/
- https://github.com/Mattiwatti/PPLKiller
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights+
- https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/10/injecting-code-into-windows-protected.html
- https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/11/injecting-code-into-windows-protected.html

Comment: First: I love GH Forum, Second: This worked whell, but, when `chunk.resize(info.RegionSize);` the program crash and the error is: Unhandled exception in 0x768C43D2 in MemoryReadTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc in memory location 0x0019F640. occurred

Comment: @DeathZ using a vector is overkill and resizing it is not necessary, just create a dynamic buffer of size regionSize.  You can't RPM or Memcpy into the address of a vector, that's not how containers work

Answer (score 0):

Processes can be protected by the callback notify. This prevents access and isolates the process from any intervention.

- http://deniable.org/windows/windows-callbacks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks

Source for example

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/obcallback-callback-registration-driver/